# Are enclosed 4D shapes really enclosed?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

Imagine we have a 4D cube (hypercube) and a 3D sphere (sphere) inside it. The hypercube consists only of its 24 (2D square) faces. The question is: are there any possibilities for the sphere to escape hypercube's internal volume without crossing any faces? Consider radius of the sphere a lot smaller than hypercube's edge length.

Remark. This question came from my computer simulation of rotating hypercube.

[3D slice of the hypercube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzYO8.jpg)

Some of 3D slices have polygon-shaped faces (but every face initially is a square, so for me it looks like that slice crosses internal volume) so I decide that it might be kinda gaps caused by some weird topology of 4D shapes.

P.S. Additional question. Is it possible to triangulate whole enclosed 4D surface (by using finite series of 2D triangles)?

UPD: As was mentioned by [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen) 2D faces of 4D shape are like wireframe. So any suggestion, what is the simplest shape (seems to be 3D) that can be used to represent solid 4D surface?

Comment: Note that 2D "faces" of a 4D hypercube play the role of 1D edges in a 3D cube. Thus escaping from your 4D situation is not harder than escaping from a wireframe-only cube in 3D

Comment: Good point. I've never thought this way. Updated my question based on your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a long comment:  For this to really be a well-posed question, the ambient space that you are working in needs to be identified.  For intuition as to what I mean here, I will ask the following question:  Can a point "escape" a circle?  Well, we think that the point must be inside the circle for this to make sense, so we probably think of the unit circle in the plane, which is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a point in the interior.  Here the answer is "No," because of the Jordan Curve theorem.

[image: circle with a point inside]

But if we change our ambient space which the circle and point are sitting in to $\mathbb{R}^3$, this is trivially not true.  We just pull the point up in the $z$ direction and the circle stays where it is.  Then the point can go where ever it wants.

[image: circle and a point inside its interior, but in a 3D view, so the point can move up and out of the circle]

PS: I would say that you cannot triangulate a 3-manifold with 2D triangles.  There are ways to talk about things like this, but I am guessing they are not what you are thinking of here.  (You can look up laminations if you want.)  You can triangulate 3-manifolds with tetrahedron instead.

UPD: For perhaps the simplest shape that has an interior in $\mathbb{R}^4$, first start with a 4-ball.  A 2-ball is a disk (the interior of a circle), a 3-ball is what kids actually call a ball, but we think of as the interior of a sphere, and the 4-ball is the one dimension up version of this.  Its boundary is the 3-sphere, $S^3$.  So things inside of the 4-ball cannot pass out of the 3-sphere into the rest of $\mathbb{R}^4$, i.e. it separates 4-space into two disjoint pieces.